# Running my Python script in my virtual env?

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

Total python noob here, I want to run my .py flask api file, i cd to my directory, activate my python virtual env, then i try run.py

Issue is that it prints:

```
$ python run.py
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "run.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy ImportError: No module named flask_sqlalchemy

As far as im aware as im in my virtualenv and have my packages installed, this shouldnt happen. Trying to `pip3 install` on any packages shows them as already existing.

To further assist with the issue, i tried to run the script inside pycharm and i get the following error prints in the log:`Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/Jack/Developer/Python/lift_api/run.py", line 26, in <module>
    sqlAlchemy.create_all() 
  File "/Users/Jack/Developer/Python/lift_api/liftapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1007, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/Users/Jack/Developer/Python/lift_api/liftapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 999, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/Users/Jack/Developer/Python/lift_api/liftapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 941, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/Users/Jack/Developer/Python/lift_api/liftapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 543, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = sqlalchemy.create_engine(info, **options)
  File "/Users/Jack/Developer/Python/lift_api/liftapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Jack/Developer/Python/lift_api/liftapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Users/Jack/Developer/Python/lift_api/liftapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 554, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'`
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: OP, when using `pip` to install, did you use `sudo`?

Comment: nope i just use pip3 install, but its already installed so this isnt the issue

Comment: Are you using python3 or python2?

Comment: python 3 hence pip3

Comment: @jwarris91 `python run.py` - shouldn't it be `python3 run.py`?

Comment: wow that actually was the fix, thanks! submit it and ill approve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run your code with python 3.x use `python3` command.

```
python3 run.py
```

Answer (score 0):

What is saying what it needs - psycopg2. If you are on Ubuntu it can help:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev python-dev
```

Then don't forget to install flask-sqlalchemy and other libraries while your virtualenv activated.

Comment: $ pip3 install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: @jwarris91, Sorry, are you using windows?

Comment: I am using a mac, it shouldnt make a difference if we are just installing packages, which doesnt seem to actually be the issue

Comment: @jwarris91 Have you tried to install psycopg2 globally? Without virtualenv?

Comment: why would i want to do that? that would be many steps backward and not resolve the issue

Comment: @jwarris91 Try to install psycopg2. I had something similar in my practice and it helped me.

Comment: @jwarris91 Try install this package globally the way it is done on MacOS - `python-psycopg2`.

Comment: no, im not installing anything globally, thats incredible poor practice, it needs to be in the virtual env not external

Comment: @jwarris91 I know very well what virtualenv is for. I do agree with you that you don't want to install it globally, but there are things which you have to install globally - without them some of the things don't work even in your virtualenv.